# using *ngIf , button disappears in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, angular-material, row

I am trying to add row to an existing material table using a button. However as I use `*ngIf` the button doesn't render.

**HTML**

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="accent" 
                           (click)="onAddRow()" 
                           *ngIf="addForm.get('rows')">Add</button>
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
        project: [null ]
    });

    this.rows = this.fb.array([]);
}

 onAddRow() {
    this.rows.push(this.createItemFormGroup());
 }

 createItemFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        name: " ",
        description: "some description",
        qty: null
    });
 }
```

Comment: you can not do addform.get('rows'), your addForm does not contain rows, rows form array is not in addForm both are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the button. It is that the formArray control is created outside of your form. Therefore when you ask for it, nothing is returned back. So if the returned value is undefined the ngIf does not allow it to be visible.

Change your constructor as the following

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
        project: [null ]
    });
    this.addForm.addControl("rows", new FormArray([]));
}
```

Comment: The button itself do not render when I added the ngif. So adding what you have suggested didn't improve.

Comment: it does not render because addForm.get('rows') doesn't return something truthy. Thats why I proposed that conversion to FormArray

Comment: I have tried both option but didn't fix I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks , it has fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`ngIf` expects a boolean value.

If you pass a method, the method's stable return value will be used. If that value is not a boolean, it must be truthy for your element to be rendered.

If you are expecting an array of items to be returned from your method, you can use the `length` property as your truthy value. If the array has no items, your element will not be shown.

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="accent" 
                           (click)="onAddRow()" 
                           *ngIf="addForm.get('rows').length">Add</button>
```

Comment: The button itself do not render when I added the ngif.